# VBA Module Termination

Tags: vba

I've got a VBA script that runs periodically.  Depending on the time base, it runs a different module.  A problem that I am running in to, that I haven't experienced before, is that as the module seems to prematurely exit.  It's making me question my methods.  It's my understanding that a module.sub is not ended or exited until it's either ended, exited, regardless of what condition ran the module.  Am I wrong?

```
Private Sub tmr1Sec_Change()
    timeBase = seconds Mod 5 'Set a 4 second time base
Select Case timeBase
                Case 1 To 2
                    errorPosition = "ThisDisplay.tmr1Sec_Change.machineState 2.1"
                        Call aofResults.orderPoll '
                Case 2 To 3
                    errorPosition = "ThisDisplay.tmr1Sec_Change.machineState 2.2"
                        If orderExists = True Then 'Set by the orderPoll Module
                            Call aofResults.linePoll
                        End If
                Case 3 To 4
                Case Else
            End Select
End Sub
```

aofResults.linePoll

```
Public Sub linePoll()
    errorPosition = "aofResults.linePoll"
    On Error GoTo errorTrap
    Err.Clear
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rstA As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rstB As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rstC As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rstD As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rstE As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim packQty As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim formFactor As Integer
    m = 0
    constr = "Provider=sqloledb;data source=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx;initial catalog=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;user id=xxxxxxxxxxx;password=xxxxxxxxxxx"
    'set the machine to recieve state
    Set conn = New ADODB.connection
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    conn.Open constr
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(lQ.[QUANTITY]) FROM [AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] AS lQ LEFT JOIN [AOF_ORDER_QUEUE] AS oQ ON lQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] = oQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER]"
    Set rst = cmd.Execute                        'Get total order quantity, may change if inventory depletes.
    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.Item("AOF\soQuantity")
    eTag.value = rst(0)
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Count(rL.SERIAL_NUMBER) FROM [AOF_OPTIC_RESULTS] AS rL WHERE EXISTS (SELECT [SO_LINE_NUMBER] FROM [AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] AS lQ LEFT JOIN [AOF_ORDER_QUEUE] AS oQ ON lQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] = oQ.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER) AND [REJECT] = 0"
    Set rst = cmd.Execute
    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.Item("AOF\soQuantityPacked")
    eTag.value = rst(0)
    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.Item("Machine\itoSettings0") 'Evaluate packing quantity against machine settings (stored in DB, written to PLC at first startup)
    If rst(0) < eTag.value Then
        Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.Item("AOF\manualPack") 'Evaluate packing quantity
        eTag.value = True
    Else
        eTag.value = False
    End If
    rst.Close
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT lQ.[SO_LINE_NUMBER],lQ.[QUANTITY],lQ.[SELECTED],lQ.[FORM_FACTOR_ID], lQ.[FINISHED_PART_NUMBER], lQ.[OEM_PART_NUMBER],lQ.[COMPATIBILITY], oQ.[INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGING], oQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] FROM [AOF_ORDER_QUEUE] AS oQ LEFT JOIN [AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] AS lQ ON oQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] = lQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] WHERE lQ.[SO_LINE_NUMBER] IS NOT NULL ORDER BY lQ.[SELECTED] DESC,lQ.[COMPLETED] ASC"
    Set rstA = cmd.Execute()                     'Returns the line orders associated to the sales order
    If Not rstA.EOF = True Then
        Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.Item("AOF\SOLineNumber")
        eTag.value = rstA(0)
        Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.Item("AOF\QuantityOrdered")
        eTag.value = rstA(1)
        Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.Item("AOF\FinishedPartNumber")
        eTag.value = rstA(4)
        Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.Item("AOF\OEMPartNumber")
        eTag.value = rstA(5)
        Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.Item("AOF\Compatibility")
        eTag.value = rstA(6)
        Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.Item("AOF\IndividualPack")
        eTag.value = rstA(7)
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(rL.SERIAL_NUMBER) FROM [AOF_OPTIC_RESULTS] AS rL LEFT JOIN [AOF_ORDER_OPTICS] AS oL ON oL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] = rL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] WHERE rL.REJECT = 0 AND oL.[SO_LINE_NUMBER] = " & rstA(0) & ""
        Set rstB = cmd.Execute()                 'Returns the count of the parts associated to the above line order that passed
        If Not rstB.EOF = True Then
            Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.Item("AOF\QuantityPassed")
            eTag.value = rstB(0)
            Select Case rstA(1) - rstB(0)        'Evaluate Qty left to process in active line order
            Case Is = 0                          'Qty Zero (Line order complete)
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(lQ.[COMPLETED]) FROM [AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] AS lQ LEFT JOIN [AOF_ORDER_QUEUE] AS oQ ON oQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] = lQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] WHERE oQ.[SELECTED] = 'True'"
                Set rstD = cmd.Execute()                 'Check line queue quantity associated to the sales order, count the line orders associated to the current sales order in the queue
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] SET [SELECTED] = 'False' WHERE [SO_LINE_NUMBER] = " & rstA(0) & ""
                cmd.Execute                      'Unselect the currently index line order
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] SET [COMPLETED] = 'True' WHERE [SO_LINE_NUMBER] = " & rstA(0) & ""
                cmd.Execute                      'Set order as completed
                'Set the currently indexed line order as selected
                If rstD(0) <> 0 Then
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(lQ.[COMPLETED]) FROM [AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] AS lQ LEFT JOIN [AOF_ORDER_QUEUE] AS oQ ON oQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] = lQ.[SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] WHERE oQ.[SELECTED] = 'True' AND [COMPLETED] = 'True'"
                    Set rstE = cmd.Execute()             'count the line orders marked completed
                    If rstD(0) = rstE(0) Then            'if the line queue count matches the line queue completed count complete the order
                        Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.Item("AOF\orderFulfillmentMode") 'Checks that order fulfillment mode is turned off
                        If eTag.value = True Then
                            boxNum = 0
                            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [AOF_ORDER_QUEUE] SET [SELECTED] = 'False' WHERE [SALES_ORDER_NUMBER] = '" & rstA(9) & "'"
                            cmd.Execute 'Set's the current sales order selected bit to off
                            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [MACHINE_STATE] SET [STATUS] = 'ERP' where [OPERATING_STATE] = 2"
                            cmd.Execute 'sets the status back to ERP
                            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM [AOF_OPTIC_RESULTS]"
                            cmd.Execute
                            Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.Item("AOF\soFinished")
                            eTag.value = True
                        End If
                    End If
                    rstE.Close
                Else
                    rstA.MoveNext                    'Index to the next line order in the record set
                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] SET [SELECTED] = 'True' WHERE [SO_LINE_NUMBER] = " & rstA(0) & ""
                    cmd.Execute
                End If
                rstD.Close

            Case Is > 0                          'Qty Remaining > Line Order Qty (Line Order Select)
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT fF.[FORM_FACTOR_DESCRIPTION] FROM [FORM_FACTOR] AS fF LEFT JOIN [AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] AS lQ ON lQ.[FORM_FACTOR_ID] = fF.[FORM_FACTOR_ID] WHERE lQ.[SELECTED] = 'True'"
                Set rstC = cmd.Execute()         'Returns the form factor description that is currently selected in the order line queue
                If Not rstC.EOF = True Then
                    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.Item("AOF\FormFactor")
                    eTag.value = rstC(0)
                    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.Item("AOF\NextOpticXFP")
                    Select Case rstC(0)
                    Case Is = "XFP"
                        eTag.value = True
                    Case Is <> "XFP"
                        eTag.value = False
                    End Select
                End If
                rstC.Close
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] SET [SELECTED] = 'True' WHERE [SO_LINE_NUMBER] = " & rstA(0) & ""
                cmd.Execute                      'Set line as selected
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT oL.[SERIAL_NUMBER],ol.[RACK],ol.[TRAY],ol.[POSITION] FROM [AOF_ORDER_OPTICS] oL WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [AOF_OPTIC_RESULTS] rL WHERE oL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] = rL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] ) AND oL.[SO_LINE_NUMBER] = " & rstA(0) & ""
                Set rstE = cmd.Execute           'Pull in the top level serial number and location for the next optic that doesn't exist in this line order
                If Not rstE.EOF = True Then
                    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.Item("AOF\NextOpticSerNo")
                    eTag.value = rstE(0)
                    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.Item("AOF\NextOpticStk")
                    eTag.value = rstE(1)
                    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.Item("AOF\NextOpticTry")
                    eTag.value = rstE(2)
                    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.Item("AOF\NextOpticPsn")
                    eTag.value = rstE(3)
                    Set eTag = ThisDisplay.eGroup.Item("AOF\ITO_OpticsReady")
                    eTag.value = True
                Else
                    MsgBox ("Error: No optics associated with line order " & rstA(0) & " exist in database")
                End If
                rstE.Close
            Case Else
            End Select
        Else
            MsgBox ("Error: No line orders exist for sales order " & rstA(4) & ".")
        End If
    ElseIf rstA.EOF = True Then
        MsgBox ("Error: No sales order exists or no line orders associated to sales order: " & rstA(4) & " exists.")
    End If
    conn.Close
cleanExit:
    '    If Not rst Is Nothing Then rst.Close
    '    If Not rstA Is Nothing Then rstA.Close
    '    If Not rstB Is Nothing Then rstB.Close
    '    If Not rstC Is Nothing Then rstC.Close
    '    If Not rstD Is Nothing Then rstD.Close
    '    If Not rstE Is Nothing Then rstE.Close
    '    If Not conn Is Nothing Then conn.Close
    Exit Sub

errorTrap:
    LogDiagnosticsMessage "_Eventwatcher.gfx, Position: " & errorPosition & " , Error Code: [ " & Hex(Err.number) & "], Description: " & Err.Description & ""
'    Set ThisDisplay.eGroup = Nothing
'    Set eTag = Nothing
    Resume cleanExit

End Sub
```

Comment: This would be easier to diagnose with the code that you *call*, not the calling code.

Comment: Added.  Disclaimer: this is proprietary VB.  eTag and eGroup are just external tag items I reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is how execution is going to go:
1. Assign timeBase with a value of 1 to 4 
(presuming that timeBase is created and seconds is created and set globally)
2. The select statement will execute once, depending on the value of timeBase.
3. End Select is reached and the select statement is exited.
4. End Sub is reached and the sub is exited.

if you want the sub to execute repeatedly, you can surround it in a for() loop or a while() loop.

Comment: If you step through, it's very two dimensional.  Is it not the same?  If I jump into a module and start working through that code, doesn't it run through it until it's finished before continuing to work through the select statement?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem, though I worry it doesn't throw a vb error.  The problem is that some of the SQL cells "can" be null, and if I try to assign a null value to a tag variable, it just exits the module without any information.